# How to split value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Here I have one month object In this month object inside value `1,2,3,4,5` and selected experience value is `04` (see console) so want to find value and I compare both but I got undefined because `4 and 04 not matched` How to match them ?

```
console.log(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])) // 04

console.log(months) // [ { value : 1, name: "one"}
                          { value: 2, name: "two" }
                          { value: 4, name: "four" } ]

console.log(months.find(month => month.value === selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])); // undefined
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to use parseInt on your "04" string. Such as `parseInt(selExp.from.split("/")[0], 10)` which will yield the number 4

Comment: The split method return a String and because of your comparison "===" with the value which is a INT, your find does not return anything

Comment: @DDD can you please stop asking people to upvote your question? I'm not sure it's entirely cool, and it's definitely annoying. If people want to upvote your question they will. Just roll with it.

Comment: @Pierce ok thank you you r right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about to convert it into an `int`?

```
console.log(months.find(month => month.value === parseInt(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])));
```

Comment: my bad ! i wanted to wrote it on the question !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
month.value === parseInt(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])
```

```js
console.log(parseInt('04') === 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) so you are comparing numbers not strings:

```
Number(month.value) === Number(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

try to convert string to number with "+" operator:

```
var test = "04";
console.log(test); //04
console.log(+test); //4

console.log(months.find(month => month.value === +selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `04` is a string , do a `parseInt` or convert it to number before comparing or else use unary operator

```
console.log(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0])) // 04
let exp = parseInt(selectedExperience.from.split('/')[0],10)

console.log(months)  // [ { value : 1, name: "one"}
                     //   { value: 2, name: "two" }
                     //   { value: 4, name: "four" }] 

console.log(months.find(month => month.value ===exp  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will return you an array of strings. So for comparing with an integer, you need to parse it using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
var test = "04/12";
var months = [{
    value: 1,
    name: "one"
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    name: "two"
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    name: "four"
  }
];

console.log(test.split('/')[0]);
console.log(months);

console.log(months.find(month => month.value === parseInt(test.split('/')[0])));
```